# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object при запуске анимации

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть класс `player` в котором находится функции остановки(`stopPlayerAnim`) и запуска(`startPlayerAnim`) анимации игрока, и класс `Joystic`, в котором они запускаются. Но когда я жму на джойстик игра вылетает со следующей ошибкой:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> player.startPlayerAnim () (at Assets/scripts/player.cs:46)
> Joystic.OnDrag (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at Assets/scripts/Joystic.cs:13)
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (UnityEngine.EventSystems.IDragHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:71)
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1] functor) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:262)
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update() (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:385)>

При этом ошибка ссылается на эту строчку: `player1.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("ball_anim", true);`

Из-за чего она появляется, и как её можно устранить? Код вышеупомянутых скриптов находится ниже:

player.cs:

```
public class player : MonoBehaviour
{
  
    public static GameObject player1;
    
    void Start()
    {
     
    }
    
    public static void startPlayerAnim()
    {

        player1.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("ball_anim", true);
        player1.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("inverted_ball_anim", false);
    }

    public static void stopPlayerAnim()
    {

        player1.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("ball_anim", false);
        player1.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("inverted_ball_anim", false);
    }

    public static void startInvertedPlayerAnim()
    {
        player1.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("inverted_ball_anim", true);
        player1.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("ball_anim", false);

    }
   
    

  
    

   

    
}
```

Comment: Проверяли значения `player1` и `player1.GetComponent<Animator>()`? Наверняка одно из них будет `null`. Кст, а где инициализация `player1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы не инициализировали `player1`, у вас просто пустое поле.
2. Также проверьте, есть ли скрипт аниматора на объекте, у которого вы пытаетесь получить компонент.